# .Net Framework Bug: System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase disposes of streams it did't create

Tags: .net

Before submitting this as a bug, I wanted to get community feedback to see if this should be considered a bug.

When creating a `LinkedResource` or other class that derives from `AttachmentBase`, there are constructor overloads that take either a [file name](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/Attachment.cs,0a9d3f581698a5b7,references) or a [`Stream`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/Attachment.cs,5072a46ba8103c1e,references). When given a file name, `AttachmentBase` internally creates a `FileStream` and assigns it the private `MimePart part` content using `MimePart.SetContent(Stream)`. When creating an `AttachmentBase` using the constructor that takes a `Stream`, it directly assigns the underlying content to this `Stream`.

When the `AttachmentBase` is [disposed](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/Attachment.cs,546805343337df9b,references), it internally disposes of the `MimePart`, which internally disposes of the `Stream` content. If the constructor taking a `Stream` was used, this `MimePart` class just disposed of a `Stream` it did not create! This bug is a side effect. Disposing of objects that a class/method doesn't own makes it impossible to reuse that object later. When creating a disposable object, that object should be able to be disposed before it is garbage collected. This allows it to free up resources like file handles captured by `FileStreams`.

Suppose you need to send out a lot of emails, and each email has one image. The image is very large, and all the emails use this same exact image. You should be able to read this file into a `MemoryStream`, and reuse this `Stream` for the `LinkedResource` in each email. This would allow little disk read and low memory usage. `Dispose()` is invoked on each message and its resources to free up any handles and unmanaged memory once the message is sent. (Again, if it implements `IDisposable`, it should be able to be disposed as soon as it's no longer needed. The code that called `Dispose()` should always be the same code that created the object.) Because this `Dispose()` method is not implemented correctly, it just disposed the underlying `Stream` to the image that it did not create. When subsequent messages try to use this `Stream`, they will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

A temporary workaround for this bug is to copy the `MemoryStream` for each message, and use the copied `Streams`. This still results in little disk read, but now the large image is copied a bunch of times in memory.

This could have all been avoided by following correct patterns and practices and allowing the code that created the `Stream` to be the one to dispose of it, and not assuming it would only be used once. Here is a fix for this bug. The code should replace the similar methods. This allows `MimePart` to be backward compatible. The change to `AttachmentBase` may be a breaking change for code that passes in a `Stream`. The fix is to handle the `Stream` you pass in by disposing of it yourself properly.

```
public abstract class AttachmentBase : IDisposable
{
    MimePart part;

    protected AttachmentBase(Stream contentStream)
    {
        part.SetContent(contentStream, true);
    }

    protected AttachmentBase(Stream contentStream, string mediaType)
    {
        part.SetContent(contentStream, null, mediaType, true);
    }

    internal AttachmentBase(Stream contentStream, string name, string mediaType)
    {
        part.SetContent(contentStream, name, mediaType, true);
    }

    protected AttachmentBase(Stream contentStream, ContentType contentType)
    {
        part.SetContent(contentStream, contentType, true);
    }
}

internal class MimePart : MimeBasePart, IDisposable
{
    private bool _keepOpen;

    internal void SetContent(Stream stream, bool keepOpen = false)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        if (streamSet && !_keepOpen)
        {
            this.stream.Dispose();
        }

        this.stream = stream;
        streamSet = true;
        streamUsedOnce = false;
        TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
        _keepOpen = keepOpen;
    }

    internal void SetContent(Stream stream, string name, string mimeType, bool keepOpen = false)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
        {
            contentType = new ContentType(mimeType);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            ContentType.Name = name;
        }

        SetContent(stream, keepOpen);
    }

    internal void SetContent(Stream stream, ContentType contentType, bool keepOpen = false)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        this.contentType = contentType;
        SetContent(stream, keepOpen);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (stream != null && !_keepOpen)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I agree that the KeepOpen option should be something supported by this API, similar to what the StreamReader does. However, your suggested implementation would probably have to include it all the way back to where the consumer creates the objects, to prevent breaking changes from being introduced.

Another way to workaround this issue is to create a wrapping stream that ignores calls to close and having an alternative way to close the stream when you are done.

For example:

```
private class UncloseableStreamWrapper : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _baseStream;
    public UncloseableStreamWrapper(Stream baseStream)
    {
        _baseStream = baseStream;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        // DO NOTHING HERE
    }

    public void CloseWrappedStream()
    {
        _baseStream.Close();
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _baseStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            _baseStream.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanRead => _baseStream.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => _baseStream.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => _baseStream.CanWrite;
    public override long Length => _baseStream.Length;
    public override void Flush() => _baseStream.Flush();
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)=> _baseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)=>_baseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    public override void SetLength(long value) => _baseStream.SetLength(value);
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _baseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

Then in your loop, you can just reset the position and go.

```
var stream = new UncloseableStreamWrapper(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"Z:\temp\temp.png"));
var lr = new LinkedResource(stream);
lr.Dispose();

stream.Position = 0;

lr = new LinkedResource(stream);
lr.Dispose();

stream.CloseWrappedStream();
Console.ReadLine();
```

One big caveat here is that you are tying your code to the implementation of the underlying `MimePart` which could change with a future update that would completely break your code.

Comment: I love your workaround because it allows the reuse of the one stream. As you said though, it relies on the implementation of the underlying code to invoke `Close()` instead of `Dispose()`. If it disposes of the stream, then you would have to override `Dispose()` in your wrapper to do nothing, which would cause `using` statements to break. After looking at quite a bit of stream source code, it appears that MS uses `Dispose()` only from other dispose calls, and uses `Close()` for everything else. I think it is mostly safe to say future changes are not likely to break your workaround.